# SparkSQL Select with multiple columns, then join?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm unfamiliar with sparksql, but want to select multiple columns in this query then join the 2 frames. The primary key column is `ID` from df.

```
val count1 = df.select(size($"col1").as("col1Name"))
val count2 = df.select(size($"col2").as("col2Name"))
```

So ultimately I want a table with `ID, count1 and count2`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please, show schema DataFrame(s) or structure table(s).

Comment: In your description you don't need to join same dataframe with itself. What are want to achieve finally?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is count 2 columns from df. You can do this using below

```
df.registerTempTable("temp_table")

//Below Is an example how you can use SparkSql

val newdf = spark.sql("select id,count(col1) as count1,count(col2) as count2 from temp_table group by id")

//You can use this dataframe further for operations

newdf.show(false)
```